# render a complete twig template extending another one with ajax in Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have my **main layout** named `layout.html.twig`. In this layout I made the block content for extends him, see the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <!-- my html code, meta header, body ... etc -->
    <body>
      <div class="col-md-12 panel panel-default" id="content">
        {% block content %}
          {# extend content to the principal layout #}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

In fact, each time I woul like to **load another page** content in my `{% block content %}`, I extends the layout like this for example in `indexEquipement.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "MyBundleBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

  {% block content %}

    <div class="page-header">
      <h4>add an equipement</h4>
    </div

    <select id="selectEquipement">
      <option selected disabled>choose an equipement</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addEquipement1') }}">Equipement 1</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addEquipement2') }}">Equipement 2</option>
    </select>

  {% endblock %}
```

This is the **route** file for the index:

```
indexEquipements:
    path:     /manageEquipements
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceMyBundle:ManageEquipements:indexEquipements }
    requirements:
    methods: GET
```

As you can see, in this example, I have a select tag with url for the values option. I try to render the view of my select choice with ajax without reloading the browser page.

Each url for the option values are in fact a view with a different form. I choose an option in my select, and ajax return in the same page the form matching with my choice.

See my controller for the Equipement 1 `addAction()`:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/manageEquipement/addEquipement1", name="addEquipement1")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function addEquipements1Action() {

    $eq = new Equipement1;

    $form = $this->createForm(new Equipement1Type(), $eq);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid())) {

        $form->bind($request);

        $em->persist($eq);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('indexEquipements'));

    }  else {

        return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:addEquipement1.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
    }
}
```

And now the **route** file for this action:

```
addEquipement1:
    path:     /manageEquipement/addEquipement1
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceMyBundle:ManageEquipements:addEquipement1 }
    requirements:
    methods: GET

addEquipement1_process:
    path:     /manageEquipement/addEquipement1/process
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceMyBundle:ManageEquipements:addEquipement1 }
    requirements:
    methods: POST
```

How can I render the form for `addEquipement1Action()` in ajax?

---

### ## EDIT ##

This the controller action for addEquipement1Action():

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/manageEquipement/addEquipement1", name="addEquipement1")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function addEquipement1Action() {

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $eq = new Equipement1;

    $form = $this->createForm(new Equipement1Type(), $eq);

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

        $template = $this->forward('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:addEquipement1.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ))->getContent();

        $json = json_encode($template);
        $response = new Response($json, 200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');


        if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid())) {

            $form->bind($request);

            $em->persist($eq);
            $em->flush();

            return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('indexEquipements'));

        }  else {

            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the index of equipement:
{% extends "MyBundleBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

```
  {% block content %}

    <div class="page-header">
      <h4>add an equipement</h4>
    </div

    <select id="selectEquipement">
      <option selected disabled>choose an equipement</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addEquipement1') }}">Equipement 1</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addEquipement2') }}">Equipement 2</option>
    </select>

    <div id="formEquipement"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#selectEquipement').change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "{{ path('addEquipement1') }}",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data){
          $("formEquipement").append(data);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

  {% endblock %}
```

When I apply a choice in my select tag, I can see when I debug in my browser that the ajax call works, but it returns me this error concerning my view I would like to display:

> The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to
>   add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

And this is my twig view for `addEquiment1.html.twig`:

```
<form action="{{ path('addEquipement1_process') }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <br>
    <div>
      {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-small btn-success"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I render this view properly in my actually page without refreshing the browser with Ajax?

Comment: http `post` verb are for create a resource, use `get` method till return a resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I render the form for addEquipement1Action() in ajax?

- you could put your form in a div container and parse it out via JS in the client
- or you separate twig views. include the form `yourform.html.twig` in the block of `indexEquipement.html.twig` and add an if statement in your controller that if a parameter `onlyForm` is set, then render `yourform.html.twig` else `indexEquipement.html.twig`. You can of course also use different routes and controler action to drop the if statement, which might would be nicer to read.

Comment: see my edit, I have updated my code for render the forms in the same view, but the error `The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?` occured. Thank you.

Comment: I understand that the controller have to return a response, but I don't understand how to make it... sorry

Comment: check all paths of all if statements. End of the method is an implicit `return null` and what if `$request->isXmlHttpRequest() == false` ?

Comment: what we're talking about here is just a PHP error okay. You must NOT return null! if `isXmlHttpRequest() == false` then there is no return statement  in your action ====> thus null is returned. If you don't understand it, learn PHP first.